# Spring boot actuator info endpoint does not return git info when running in azure app service

Tags: spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, spring-boot-actuator

Here is a repository with the demonstration:
https://github.com/teplyuska/spring-boot-actuator-info-demo

Check the readme for more details

Here is a short description of what it contains.

1. Use git-commit-id-maven-plugin to create git.properties file
2. Use spring-boot-starter-actuator and related configs to include full git info in the actuator info endpoint.
3. Start the app normally shows git info
4. Start the app using azure app service image does not show git info

Comment: Why aren't you running it with `java -jar your.jar` as you normally would?

Comment: When using azure app service, the image your application is started in, is provided as a service by Microsoft. I don't know the specifics of why they have chosen to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the additional jar files added by java -cp already contained a git.properties file with information about the additional jar.

```
{"git.commit.message.short"="Merged PR 7721155: [ANT101] Merge Dev into Master",, "git.remote.origin.url"="https://msazure.visualstudio.com/One/_git/AAPT-Antares-Websites-Extensions-Java",, "git.dirty"="false",, "git.closest.tag.name"="",, "git.branch"="5d33e9c40fdd4248b64cf6242ae5eeabac44a1c6",, "git.tags"="",, "git.build.time"="2023-03-05T03:43:51+0000",, "git.commit.id.describe-short"="5d33e9c",, "git.closest.tag.commit.count"="",, "git.local.branch.ahead"="NO_REMOTE",, "git.commit.message.full"="Merged PR 7721155: [ANT101] Merge Dev into Master

Merged PR 7698940: Add dependency on commons-text 1.10.0 to mitigate CVE-2022-42889

Related work items: #17158979",, "git.commit.id.describe"="5d33e9c",, "git.commit.time"="2023-03-05T03:30:25+0000",, "git.total.commit.count"="111", "git.build.version"="1.0",, {=, "git.commit.id"="5d33e9c40fdd4248b64cf6242ae5eeabac44a1c6",, "git.local.branch.behind"="NO_REMOTE",, "git.commit.id.abbrev"="5d33e9c",, }=}
```

How to find:
https://github.com/teplyuska/spring-boot-actuator-info-demo/commit/8fb8ae5da1495bd83045c46bda021d46729adc3d

To solve this i added:

```
<generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/my-git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
```

and

```
spring.info.git.location=classpath:my-git.properties
```

More info:
https://github.com/teplyuska/spring-boot-actuator-info-demo/commit/9b42b6d432dfcc982ec5bcc0d5c8e67eca78c0e8